# How often was Tool Time aired, in-universe?

Tags: home-improvement

Within the Home Improvement universe, Tool Time was Tim Taylor's cable show that aired in Michigan.

Tim is generally shown going to work five days a week, although I would imagine each episode also requires writing, prep time, etc (not to mention time for fixing all of Tim's mistakes).

The airing frequency of Tool Time seems somewhat inconsistent. Sometimes it's referred to as a daily show, which other times it seems weekly.

Is it ever mentioned precisely how frequently the show was produced and aired in-universe?

That is, was it a weekly show, a daily show, or some other interval?

Comment: As a sidenote, I think it's fairly realistic that being the anchor of a weekly show, especially one that contains weekly projects, amounts to a full-time job. Maybe not quite as nine-to-five-y as portrayed in the show, but still ...

Comment: I don't think so, Tim

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### **Normally weekly**

- **Episode 1x6 ("Adventures in Fine Dining")**

> **Tim:** *Because I want you to remember, men, the first three letters of "manners" are... (grunts) **See you next week!** (grunts)*

- **Episode 1x10 ("Reach Out and Teach Someone")**

> **Tim:** *Well, this is gonna be different, 'cause on **next week's show**,*

- **Episode 2x2 ("Rites & Wrongs of Passage")**

> **Tim:** *While Al cleans up his little mess, let me tell you about **next week's show.***

- **Episode 3x5 ("Arrivederci, Binford")**

> **Tim:** *Al, why don't you tell us what's on **the next show?***
> **Al:** ***Next week,** we'll be doing our salute to electrical...*

- **Episode 8x16 ("Mark's Big Break")**

> **Tim:** *And I'm thinking that if we brainstorm with some of the guys down at Tool Time, we could come up with **a great episode for next week.***

### Occasionally they do week-long shows, one per day.

- **Episode 7x22 ("Believe It or Not")**

> **Tim:** *All week long we've been showing you things that make our lives easier.*

- **Episode 1x22 ("Luck Be a Taylor Tonight")**

> **Tim:** *All this week, Al and I have done our Tool Time salute to painting*

- **Episode 3x02 ("Aisle See You in My Dreams")**

> **Tim:** *It's Male Hobby Week all this week on Tool Time. And today, Al and I are doing our Tool Time salute...to fishing.*

- **Episode 2x24 ("Birth of a Hot Rod")**

> **Tim:** *Why don't we tell the folks what we have coming up on Lawn Care Week.*
>
> **Al:** *Well, Tim, tomorrow, we'll be doing our salute... to clippers. On Wednesday, we'll be doing our salute...to sprinklers. But today, we're doing our salute (moo) to fertilizer.*

- **Episode 6x21 ("Insult to Injury")**

> **Tim:** *Before we get to that, I have a big announcement. On tomorrow's show, I will break the record for consecutive appearances on a home remodelling show. How about that, huh?*

Comment: Those quotes are pretty bang on, thanks! I agree, that seems most likely. I feel like some dialog though  indicates it might be more than weekly. For instance in 1x24, Tim says "all this week, we'll be doing our salute to saws". To me, that implies there could be multiple episodes in their (week long) "salute to saws".

Comment: @Tronman - You're not wrong. See edits :-)

Comment: Nice! Yeah, that confirms my suspicion that it was treated inconsistently by the writers. I guess episodes of Tool Time were made "as often as we need them". Thanks!

Comment: It's possible that all the "next week" quotes aired on a Friday. Is there any way to verify?

Comment: @OrangeDog - I can think of several times when  Tim has had to wait for his kids to come home from school before doing projects with them. That would suggest that the show is on a weekday, at the very least

Answer (score -1):

The show was aired every week :

> Tim "The Tool Man" Taylor was the host of a regionally syndicated home improvement show called "Tool Time"," produced and sponsored by Binford Tools. **Every week** there was a "salute" to some different theme like woodworking, or lawnmowers, and a subsequent project that he would work on assisted by his co-host Al "This land is" Borland.

From [Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/home-improvement-show-weird-things/#why-tim-still-had-a-show).

> Each week, through Tim's error, something would go wrong on the show, but that's why his audience loved him. [Collider - 'Home Improvement' Ending](https://collider.com/home-improvement-ending-explained/)

Comment: This appears to be quotes from various sources unconnected with the show. It's also not clear if they mean in-universe.

Comment: they're just *different* sources, no need to quote/use the same or already quoted ones.

Comment: The quotes in my answer are from the actual show. These are a much lower quality of source, e.g. Written by people who were in no way connected to the show and appear to have no special insight. How are these, for example, any better than fanfic or something you've written yourself?

Comment: Great. I see your point and understand your DV, no problem.

Comment: Attributions don't go *in* the quote.

Comment: Also this is wrong, but that's an entirely different problem :-)